# Novice question about structuring events in Tcl/Tk

Tags: events, tcl, tk-toolkit

If one is attempting to build a desktop program with a semi-complex GUI, especially one in which users can open multiple instances of identical GUI components such as having a "project" GUI and permitting users to open multiple projects concurrently within the main window, is it good practice to push the event listeners further up the widget hierarchy and use the event detail to determine upon which widget the event took place, as opposed to placing event listeners on each individual widget?

For example, in doing something similar in a web browser, there were no event listeners on any individual project GUI elements.  The listeners were on the parent container that held the multiple instances of each project GUI. A project had multiple tabs within its GUI, but only one tab was visible within a project at a time and only one project was visible at any one time; so, it was fairly easy to use classes on the HTML elements and then the `e.matches()` method on the `event.target` to act upon the currently visible tab within the currently visible project in a manner that was independent of which project it was that was visible. Without any real performance testing, it was my unqualified impression as an amateur that having as few event listeners as possible was more efficient and I got most of that by reading information that wasn't very exact.

I read recently in John Ousterhout's book that Tk applications can have hundreds of event handlers and wondered whether or not attempting to limit the number of them as described above really makes any difference in Tcl/Tk.

My purpose in asking this question is solely to understand events better in order to start off the coding of my Tcl/Tk program correctly and not have to re-code a bunch of poorly structured event listeners.  I'm not attempting to dispute anything written in the mentioned book and don't know enough to do so if I wanted to.

Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having hundreds of event handlers is usually just a mark that there's a lot of different events possibly getting sent around. Since you usually (but not always) try to specialize the binding to be as specific as possible, the actual event handler is usually really small, but might call a procedure to do the work. That tends to work out well in practice. Myself, my rule of thumb is that if it is not a simple call then I'll put in a helper procedure; it's easier to debug them that way. (The main exception to my rule is if I want to generate a `break`.)

There are four levels you can *usually* `bind` on (plus more widget-specific ones for `canvas` and `text`):

1. ***The individual widget.*** This is the one that you'll use most.
2. The widget class. This is mostly used by Tk; you'll usually *not* want to change it because it may alter the behaviour of code that you just use. (For example, don't alter the behaviour of buttons!)
3. ***The toplevel containing the widget.*** This is ideal for hotkeys. (Be very careful though; some bindings at this level can be trouble. `<Destroy>` is the one that usually bites.) Toplevel widgets themselves don't have this, because of rule 1.
4. `all`, which does what it says, and which you almost never need.

You can define others with `bindtags`… but it's usually not a great plan as it is a lot of work.

The other thing to bear in mind is that Tk supports virtual events, `<<FooBarHappened>>`. They have all sorts of uses, but the main one in a complex application (that you should take note of) is for defining higher-level events that are triggered by a sequence of low-level events occasionally, and yet which other widgets than the originator may wish to take note of.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  When learning JS events, I wondered why anyone would ever use custom events (which appear to be quite similar to virtual events); but, now, from reading the Tcl/Tk book and your answer, I'm beginning to see the benefit of them, especially for allowing code added in the future to work without having to alter the original code.

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question, please? I tried to make it a separate question but it was closed. In Ousterhout's book, page 19, the last bullet includes parenthetically that "Tk provides a library that you can use to create new widget classes and geometry managers in C, but this capability is rarely used and so is not covered in this book."  Where is it covered?  I'm interested in seeing if I can understand this and try it.  Thank you.

Comment: There's no book covering that as far as I'm aware, as it is really not commonly used. But if you're interested in doing it, read the Tk source code. It's well-written and the best guide to how to do things well I know.

Comment: I came across an older book from 1997 entitled Practical Programming in Tcl & Tk by Brian Welch which has a chapter containing an example of writing a Tk widget in C.